# Why is document.body.scrollHeight returning different number?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to get the total height of the body so I was using
`let page = document.body.scrollHeight` [The console is telling me that the height of my body in this scroll shot is 4728.120px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnFTr.png). With that said, I'm logging `page` to the console. Initially I get `4728px`. Then after refreshing the page, I'm getting `2029px`. I don't understand why that number would ever change, especially considering the window hasn't been resized.

```
  let backgrounds = [
    "background_1.jpg",
    "background_2.jpg",
    "background_3.jpg",
    "background_4.jpg",
    "background_5.jpg",
    "background_6.jpg",
    "background_7.jpg",
    "background_8.jpg",
    "background_9.jpg",
    "background_10.jpg",
    "background_11.jpg",
    "background_12.jpg",
    "background_13.jpg",
    "background_14.jpg",
    "background_15.jpg",
    "background_16.jpg",
    "background_17.jpg",
    "background_18.jpg"
  ],
  i = 0;

  var page       = document.querySelector('body').scrollHeight,
      base       = backgrounds.length,
      height     = page / base,
      increment  = height;
  console.log(page);
  let points = Array(base).fill().map((_, i) => height+=increment)
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    console.log(i,points[i]);
    if (scroll >= points[i]) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${backgrounds[i]})`;
      i++;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Do you have a sample code? I am wondering if it has to do with images loading or dynamic content.

Comment: The body is not the same size as the window, the body will resize to fit the content unless you do some styling to make it always be the size of the window

Comment: @nitobuendia I've updated the original post to show what exactly I'm trying to do. Essentially, trying to get the height of the document, and divide the height of the body by the length of my `backgrounds` array so that on scroll, it changes the background of the image so that when the user hits the end of the page, all images have cycled through.

Comment: Perhaps the document you are trying to read is lazily loading images, so it pads itself before a full asset load to accommodate for the soon-to-be-populated images.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your code is that you want to change the background when the user is scrolling down (note that your code does not change it back when scrolling up).

Based on that assumption, I have done a working demo. Simply run the code snippet and scroll the bottom right box.

```js
const backgrounds = [
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1020315/pexels-photo-1020315.jpeg',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/255379/pexels-photo-255379.jpeg',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/207171/pexels-photo-207171.jpeg',
];
const mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');

const pageHeight = mainDiv.scrollHeight;
const backgroundHeight = Math.round(pageHeight / backgrounds.length);

const changePoints = backgrounds.map((value, index) => {
  const nextPoint = backgroundHeight * index;
  return nextPoint;
});
changePoints.push(pageHeight);

console.log(pageHeight, backgroundHeight, changePoints);


let currentBackgroundIndex = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scroll = document.body.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset;
  const nextChangePoint = changePoints[currentBackgroundIndex];
  console.log(scroll, nextChangePoint);
  
  if (scroll > nextChangePoint) {
   const currentBackground = backgrounds[currentBackgroundIndex];
    currentBackgroundIndex++;
    mainDiv.style.backgroundImage = `url(${currentBackground})`;
    console.log('Changing background',
      currentBackgroundIndex, currentBackground);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  height: 2000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, as for your question on why would scrollHeight change. I was not able to replicate the behaviour with your given code. My best guess is that you may be checking it at time X and the body might still be parsing and loading elements. For example, imagine you load two images each of them being 50px and your body 100px. If you measure scrollHeight without images you'd get 100; if after one image is loaded 150px and if at the very end 200px.

Some techniques to avoid this:

1. Add height to all your elements.
2. Delay the execution of this code, or recompute the calculations after a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for this, this has been really helpful. If I'm derring the JS, would that be part of the issue? @nitobuendia

Comment: Michael, I am not sure what derring means, sorry. Could you kindly clarify? :)

Comment: oops typo. Deferring
`<script src="./scripts/app.js" defer></script>`

Comment: defer would simply make the script to load after the document is parsed. I would definitely wait at least until DOMContentLoaded. However, this one also does not wait for changes in your style or images; so you are still stuck on the same point. You really need to wait or recompute after all images and CSS changes, etc are fully completed to get consistent behaviour. Unfortunately, there is no straight forward thing for that. You could have a look at the ResizeObservers though and see if that helps as a trigger to recompute: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver